# Modal view not showing up

Tags: ios, modal-dialog

My application is basically a TableView application with few Modal views. There is a login Modal that shows if screen is not active for a specific time interval. User should enter the passcode to see the application window.

Problem: When table view is active screen, timeout login view (Modal) shows properly, but when any Modal is active screen, no Login modal shows up. I have no idea how to deal with this.

This is how I am showing login Modal.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    LoginViewController *controller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryBoard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];
    [self.window.rootViewController  presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

I am using Xcode 4.2.1

Any help on this would be a great help.

Thanks
Alok

Comment: Are you sure controller is not nil?

Comment: yeah .. its not nil. Its working perfect when active screen is a table view.

Comment: I was having the same problem but found that [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490655/dismiss-modal-view-controller-on-application-exit) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `controller` is not nil,and

in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` use

```
[self.window setRootViewController:rootController];
```

not

```
[self.window addSubview:rootController.view];
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I checked controller is not nil. also no luck after adding [self.window setRootViewController:rootController];

Answer (score 0):

`[self.window.rootViewController  presentModalViewController:controller1 animated:YES];`

`[self.window.rootViewController  presentModalViewController:controller2 animated:YES];`

Only one modal view is allowed. The controller2 will not be shown.
If viewcontroller has a modalviewcontroller, no other view controller can be presented by this viewcontroller.